# Problemla con HTMLInputElement

Tags: javascript, html

No he podido resolver este error: cuando selecciono la opción "ciudades pequeñas y medianas", me imprime por consola `HTMLInputElement {}`, en lugar de "10".

Las otras opciones funcionan correctamente imprimiendo el valor asignado en el código. Supongo que tiene que ver con el *input* que imprime el resultado donde se esta generando el problema, la verdad no estoy segura.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>ttt</title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    
    <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Seleccione Entorno</div>
    <div class="card-content p-4">
    <form>
    <select name="Entorno" id="Entorno">
    <option disabled selected>Elija una opci&oacute;n</option>
    <option value="Cuidades">Cuidades pequenas y medianas</option>
    <option value="metropolitana">&Aacute;rea metropolitana</option>
    <option value="suburbano">Ambiente suburbano</option>
    <option value="rural">&Aacute;rea rural</option>
    </select> 
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
    <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">Resultado</div>
    <input id="r" type="text" data-role="input" data-prepend="Resultado : " data-append="dB" disabled>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>                   
    </div>      
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
    Entorno = document.getElementById("Entorno");
          
    Entorno.addEventListener('click', function () {
                 
    if (document.getElementById("Entorno").value === "Ciudades"){
    
    r = 10;
    document.getElementById('r').value = r;
                  
    }
    if (document.getElementById("Entorno").value === "metropolitana"){
            
    r = 2;
    document.getElementById('r').value = r;
    }
    
    if (document.getElementById("Entorno").value === "suburbano"){
    r = 3;
    document.getElementById('r').value = r;
    
    }
    if (document.getElementById("Entorno").value === "rural" ){
    r = 4;
    document.getElementById('r').value = r;
    }
    console.log(r);          
     });
    
    
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Yo probé tu código y veo que si funciona a nivel del HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bienvenida, acabo de revisar tu código, y seguro reirás conmigo, usaste arriba `Cuidades` y abajo `Ciudades`, solo estaba mal eso, además puse que cambies en el addEventListener a `change` que es lo recomendable cuando usas selects.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>ttt</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">Seleccione Entorno</div>
        <div class="card-content p-4">
          <form>
            <select name="Entorno" id="Entorno">
              <option disabled selected>Elija una opci&oacute;n</option>
              <option value="Ciudades">Cuidades pequenas y medianas</option>
              <option value="metropolitana">&Aacute;rea metropolitana</option>
              <option value="suburbano">Ambiente suburbano</option>
              <option value="rural">&Aacute;rea rural</option>
            </select>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">Resultado</div>
        <input id="r" type="text" data-role="input" data-prepend="Resultado : " data-append="dB" disabled>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    Entorno = document.getElementById("Entorno");
    Entorno.addEventListener('change', function() {
      if (document.getElementById("Entorno").value === "Ciudades") {
        r = 10;
        document.getElementById('r').value = r;

      }
      else if (document.getElementById("Entorno").value === "metropolitana") {

        r = 2;
        document.getElementById('r').value = r;
      }

      else if (document.getElementById("Entorno").value === "suburbano") {
        r = 3;
        document.getElementById('r').value = r;

      }
      else if (document.getElementById("Entorno").value === "rural") {
        r = 4;
        document.getElementById('r').value = r;
      }
      console.log(r);
    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, ahora todo funciona correctamente.

Comment: Si la respuesta de Felipe fue útil, entonces acéptala como respuesta válida, de esta manera otros usuarios sabrán que te ha servido.